# JQuery Plugin with 2 Selectors

Tags: jquery

I created a JQuery tooltip plugin which can be used in two ways:

- The tooltip content is the title of the HTML anchor;
- The tooltip content is passed as an option;

I would like to have another option:

- The entire tooltip markup would be an element in the page.

  Let me give an example of what I am looking for:

  $("table td.Task a.Menu", "li div.Menu").Tooltip();

  So every link Menu under "table td.Task" would fire a tooltip.

  The tooltip markup would be the div.Menu under the same LI of the a.Menu

How to change my plugin to also being able to do this? My current code is:

```
(function ($) {

  $.fn.Tooltip = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
      content: "",
      class: "Tooltip",
      id: "Tooltip"
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    var tooltip;

    $(this).each(function () {

      var title = $(this).attr("title");
      if (title == undefined && options.content == "") return;

      $(this).mouseenter(function (e) {

        $(this).removeAttr("title")
        tooltip = "<div id='{id}' class='{class}'>{content}</div>"

        var content = options.content == "" ? title : options.content;
        tooltip = tootip.replace("{class}", options.class).replace("{id}", options.id).replace("{content}", content);

        $("body").append(tooltip);
        $("#" + options.id).fadeIn("fast");

      }), // Mouse Enter

      // Mouse Leave, Mouse Down and Mouse Move functions ...

    }
   }
```

Thank You!

Comment: Hi Mighuel, I removed your signature from a couple of your posts, as on SE signatures are discouraged. See FAQ or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going to rewrite the whole plugin but could add an option that returns content from page:

```
var defaults = {
      content: "",
      class: "Tooltip",
      id: "Tooltip",
      contentSource: 'title' /* "title" as default or "html" for in page*/
      htmlSource: function($el){
         /* write whatever traverse returns content wanted*/
         return  $el.siblings('div.foo').html();
      }
    };
```

Now when you set content check which source

```
/* should cache $(this) since using it numerous times*/
var $this=$(this)


var content;
if( options.contentSource !='title'){
   content=options.htmlSource($this);
}else{
  content= /* existing code*/
}
```

Usege:

```
$("table td.Task a.Menu", "li div.Menu").Tooltip({
      contentSource: 'html',
      htmlSource: function($el){            
          return  $el.parent().find('.someClass').html();
      }
});
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and something strange happens. I added the DIV to my page: "<div class=".someClass">Text</div>". In this case the tooltip shows. But if I have "<div class=".someClass"><ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></div>" then it does not show. I have no idea why. Do you know why this happens? Thank You

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net. Have no idea what html or traverse you are using

Comment: also see you have a `dot` in `class=".someClass"` which isn't correct

Comment: Hello, JSFiddle was having a few problems so I used the following: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbvnG ... I am not sure I implemented everything as you suggested. One thing that is looking strange is the last one: it should not show a tooltip but somehow it shows ... Any idea why? I wasn't able to figure this out. Any suggestion to improve my code is welcome. Thank You

Comment: problem with last one is `var source = options.source($(this));`.  `siblings().html()` is not `undefined` and will return html of first sibling. Need better condition tests but having option to me that clearly specifies where data should come from seems most sensible to me `contenTsource` as

Comment: What do you mean with using contentSource? Specifying the id of the target? The problem is I am applying this on a list of items. And i do not know the IDs. So this is why I am using the relation to the anchor which I am pressing.

Comment: as in my example in answer. Only access the `source` function if option to use it is set to `"html"`. Also in your example...if you just return `null` as default instead of the `siblings().html()` you used it would also work. The `if(source == undefined` would be true. Right now it isn't true, so that's why you see the text from very first link in your tooltip

Comment: if no source and no title => do nothing  demo that returns `null` by default  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fepkK...I only changed one line